# scrollable view in android sdk

Tags: java, android, android-layout, sdk

I am having problem dealing with scrollable view.
What I want to do is read an input and write corresponding result below it and then again read another input under the previous output and so on in a loop until a condition is satisfied.

Comment: please add some code...

Comment: i have no idea how to proceed so i have no code. i tried it using it with textview but failed.

Comment: add the **parent scroll view**. Then read the input in a different layout say _relative layout_, show output in another layout below previous input, and so for another input and output all in the **Scroll View Layout**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parent scroll view. Something like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Your content here--> 

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```